# Showing a header and under it a paragraph is not wokring correctly on wide screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code which uses bootstrap 4.0 to show a `<h1>` following by a `<p>`, as follow:-

```html
<div row style="display:none" id="hideshow" class=" row justify-content-center">
<h1 style="color:#4d9b84 ;font-weight: 700;font-size:25px;margin-top: 15px; ">**********</h1>
<p style="color: #96999b; font-weight: 700; font-size: 100%; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 15px; ">********</p>
</div>
```

now on my 14 inch screen i will get this correct layout, header under it the paragraph:-
[image]

while on 17 inch or wider screens i will get this layout, header beside it the paragraph:-
[image]

so can anyone advice? why the layout got corrupted inside the 17 inch screens?

Comment: why a down vote?

Comment: check in your browser console what happens and what class are applied when you are on 17 inch screen

Comment: @Sfili_81 no new classes just the 2 components will be shown beside each other. as if they are on the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because your using flex,which by default is set to row, and when there is not enough room it will wrap. so on small screen it wraps to 2 lines but on a larger screen it goes side by side.

To mitigate it you need to set the flex to column:

```
//I've added flex-column to the top div
<div row style="display:none" id="hideshow" class=" row justify-content-center flex-column">
<h1 style="color:#4d9b84 ;font-weight: 700;font-size:25px;margin-top: 15px; ">**********</h1>
<p style="color: #96999b; font-weight: 700; font-size: 100%; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 15px; ">********</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The 'style="display:none"' should be removed too. Since the display is flex.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
.myDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <h1>h1**********</h1>
  <p>p************</p>
</div>
```